# App icon on phone looks squished in Unity

Tags: unity

I am working on a 2D platformer. And I am alomost finished!! I am trying to work on adding the app icon. The icon that you would see on your phone. I imported the picture and added it to player settings. But when I put my game on my phone the icon looks squished. These are the settings that I imported it on

Texture Type (sprite 2D and UI)

sprite mode Single

Filter mode Blinear (not pixel art)

Here is a link to a screen shot on my phone of the icon

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbgciscda7nykjd/app%20on%20phone.png?dl=0

Ok I am getting closer to an solution now. My first problem was that the image was not square as staed below. But now the image is smaller compared to the rest of the app icons. the resolution of teh image now is 2000X2000

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like now

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t45vylzpi3chnsf/App_Icon_2.png?dl=0

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: The dimensions are 2000 X 1537 here is a screenshot of all the import settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezjo2dxla63t9k0/inspector.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon needs to be square. Add some empty space on the top and bottom to pad it out to 2000x2000, or trim some empty space off the sides to make it 1537x1537 (or somewhere in between)

Actually it looks like there’s a fair bit of blank space in the icon already. You may want to crop all the white space out first, then add padding as necessary.

Comment: That did fix the issue of the image looking squished! But now that image looks smaller from the normal looking app icon. Is that something that will get fixed when I publish? Or do I have to fix that? Here is a screenshot of it compared to another App Icon https://www.dropbox.com/s/t45vylzpi3chnsf/App_Icon_2.png?dl=0

Comment: You should get rid of as much extra space around the edge of the image as possible while still keeping it square. That should make it larger.